# Laravel Use a folder instead of 1 controller

Tags: laravel, controller

I have dozens of controllers that i need to use in a main controller I have

Instead of doing something like:

```php
Use App\Http\Controllers\Animals\Cat;
Use App\Http\Controllers\Animals\Dog;
Use App\Http\Controllers\Animals\Fish;
Use App\Http\Controllers\Animals\Bird;
Use App\Http\Controllers\Animals\Tiger;
Use App\Http\Controllers\Animals\Shark;

class MyAnimals extends BaseController
{
    $cats = Cat::getCat();
    $dogs = Dog::getDog();
    // etc
}
```

Is there a way I can just use an entire folder? something like:

```php
Use App\Http\Controllers\Animals\
      
class MyAnimals extends BaseController
{
    $cats = Cat::getCat();
    $dogs = Dog::getDog();
    // etc
}
```

I know this has probably been answered a lot, I just cant find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If your controllers share a namespace, then you don't need to include them.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Animals;

class MyAnimals extends BaseController
{
    $cats = Cat::getCat(); // Cat here is assumed to be App\Http\Controllers\Animals\Cat;
}
```

Also, the keyword is `use`, not `Use`. A case-sensitive server could give you problems with that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
Use App\Http\Controllers\Animals\{
    Cat, Dog, Fish, Bird, Tiger, Shark
};
```

If you want to make it dynamic, you can create a function to read the folder content and call each class one by one.

```
public function handle()
{
    $animals = [];

    foreach ((new Filesystem)->files(__DIR__ . '/Animals') as $animal) {
        $animal = str_replace('.php', '', $animal);

        $animals[$animal] = (__NAMESPACE__ . "\\{$animal}")::get();
    }

    return $animals;
}
```